# Как лучше организовать выгрузку данных справочника 1с 7.7 в MySQL?

Tags: 1с

Задача - вывести справочник на сайт.

Я представляю себе это таким образом. Выгружаем справочник в dbf (алгоритм под вопросом). Передаем dbf-ник серверу (LAMP) через POST, обрабатываем при помощи PHP, загоняем данные в MySQL.

Я так понимаю, 1с сама не умеет посылать GET/POST запросы? А если 1с-ка у меня будет формировать текстовый файл с SQL-кодом для всех необходимых вставок? Таким образом не надо будет возиться с dbf! Это плюс к универсальности, потому что у хостинг-провайдера может быть отключен модуль dbase.

Comment: Можешь напрямую например используя EF 
Code First и Linq to EF на примере 1С версии 7.7 и 8.3 часть I   http://infostart.ru/public/393228/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в сети вот такой код для семерки. Об 1с++ ничего не сказано

```
WinHttp=СоздатьОбъект("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttp.Option(2,"Windows-1251");                   
WinHttp.Open("POST","http://sta.gov.ua/control/uk/vat/search",0);

// Вторым параметром передаем GET-данные 
// param1=value1&param2=value2"

// WinHttp.SetProxy(0,"192.168.1.1:3128");// Задаем параметры своего прокси сервера
// WinHttp.SetCredentials("ProxyLogin","ProzyPassword",1);

// Задаем параметром логин и пароль         
// Если прямое соединение то так в коментах и оставлем :)        
WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset","Windows-1251");
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Language", "ru"); 
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Charset", "Windows-1251"); 
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=Windows-1251");

ПараметрыПОСТ = "isJuridical=1" + "&individualCode="+СокрЛП(Контрагент.ЕДРПОУ);

// Параметром передаем POST-данные для страници тут как раз            
WinHttp.Send(ПараметрыПОСТ);

// Дальше или сохраняем страницу в файл
Текст = СоздатьОбъект("Текст");
Текст.ДобавитьСтроку(WinHttp.ResponseText());
Текст.Записать(КаталогИБ() + "otvet.htm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего подключить внешнюю компоненту 1с++ или Addin.MySQLConnection и с её помощью подключаться к базе напрямую.
Есть еще простой способ: создать текстовый CSV-файл, каким-либо способом передать/забрать на сервер, и средствами php (или другого серверного языка) распарсить и внести в базу.
Посмотрите примеры на [forum.mista.ru](http://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=511843) и [infostart.ru](http://infostart.ru/public/14340/).

Comment: А если хостер не дает напрямую подключатся к mysql? Первый вариант не подходит. Второй - надо выгружать файл, затем брать его, и слать на сервер, в скрипт - бухгалтеру придется делать уже два действия.
В идеале 1с-ка сама обратится к php-скрипту, передав туда post'ом все что надо, а скрипт, естественно распарсит, и внесет в базу.

Comment: Пробуйте. Возможно, через 1с++.
И во втором варианте можно все автоматизировать, или упростить (тоже через 1с++).